# Input filter to reduce conducted emissions caused by DC/DC converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, filter, buck, emi-filtering

This [material](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/ic/power/input-filter-for-dcdc-converter_an-e.pdf) from ROHM explains the input filter design for a DC/DC converter.

The filter circuit is given below.

[image]

I understood the design of Lf, Cf2, Cd and Rd.

If you see the 3rd page (design of input filter,) they explain the design of Cf1.

You can see that they are directly selecting a value of 4.7 uF.

How did they arrive that value? Can I select any value for Cf1?

How to design Cf1?

For designing Lf and Cf2 they say:

> it is recommended to select an inductor with an inductance SRF value lower than the capacitance value of the filter capacitor

Why?

Comment: Assume Cf1=Cf2 as a starting point for your simulations and/or tests.

Comment: In the document you quote, it is said: "The capacitance of the first filter capacitor (CF1) must be chosen with a self-resonance frequency close to the switching frequency". In your application, the switching frequency is 2.2 MHz and a 4.7µF capacitor has a satisfactory SFR (self-resonance frequency close to the switching frequency). Other values of CF1 are possible if the above condition is respected.

Comment: Ideally SFR of CF1 should be  more than Switching frequency. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything starts with the current signature of the dc-dc converter fed by the EMI filter. For instance, you simulate your converter at steady-state and extract the input current. If the EMI filter is well designed, most of the high-frequency pulses will go through capacitor \$C_{F1}\$ while dc and some ripple will flow through inductor \$L_f\$. It is this amount of acceptable ac ripple in \$L_f\$ that you need to define based on the standard you want to fulfill.

All the calculation flow, including damping, is detailed in my [APEC 2017](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf) seminar. I will however take another example here. Assume a classical voltage-mode boost converter operated at a 100-kHz frequency. Extract the input current and obtain the fundamental value at 100 kHz:

[image]

Now, we assume your spec limits the ripple at 10 mA peak at 100 kHz. You thus must attenuate this noise by a certain amount knowing the amplitude of the fundamental at 100 kHz. The calculation gives an attenuation of 0.0323 or a 30-dB attenuation but we will take some margin there:

[image]

Knowing the transfer function of this \$LC\$ filter (see my [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651515/input-filter-transfer-function-derivation/651522#651522)), you know how to select the inductor and the capacitor. Considering the input current and associated losses, you may want to minimize the inductance and grow the capacitor. Most certainly the occupied volume adds another constraint and you will need to run a few iterations before finding the right combination. When you have it, another quick sim tells you if you approach the target:

[image]

The input current ripple is now around 20 mA peak-to-peak, and perhaps we could select a slightly lower cutoff frequency and run the calculation again but you see the idea.

That being said, once you have selected the right \$LC\$ couple, it is important to characterize their individual magnitude response versus frequency: extract their parasitics like inter-winding capacitance and ESR for instance as they will defeat the filter attenuation. These elements with their individual resonance will affect the filter to reject the noise and you may need to select other components to meet your goal.

Finally, do not forget the interaction between this front-end filter output impedance and the negative incremental resistance of the downstream dc-dc converter: you must damp the filter you have designed. In the Rohm AN, they determine a damping resistor and then select the dc-block capacitor with an empirical relationship. This usually leads to large dc-block capacitors. If you look through my APEC seminar, you will see how you can find an optimum damping combination which minimizes the capacitor value for exactly meeting your goal.

Comment: This is very informative,thank you.May I knw which tool you are using for simulation purpose

Comment: The circuit I used for illustration purposes is coming from my [ready-made](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) free SIMPLIS simulation templates. Most of the examples I provide work on the free demo version [Elements](https://www.simplistechnologies.com/product/elements). You will find a tutorial on my [web page](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm) if you want to look at this simulator.

Comment: ,if you don't mind could you please check this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660477/buck-converter-inductance-vs-line-and-load-regulation?noredirect=1#comment1756997_660477