# Buck converter inductance vs Line and load regulation

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

I know how to design the inductor and capacitor for a buck converter.

My question is let the calculated value of the inductance be some "**X**".

May I know what will happen to line and load regulation of the buck converter if

1. I used an inductor whose value is less than **"X"**?
2. If I used an inductor whose value is more than **"X"**?

Can you please explain with equations.

Comment: Line and load regulation is unaffected but, ripple voltage will change.

Comment: @Andyaka,Thank you.If you don't mind could you please an explanation why Line and load regulation is unaffected.

Comment: U=L*di/dt. Apply for your case. Try simulating it too or test it on a PCB and probe it to build your understanding.

Comment: Line and load regulation don't change, theoretically (i.e. neglecting the parasitic components such as trace resistance, DCR of the inductor, etc.). But the response time to step change of either input voltage or output load changes.

Comment: @RohatKılıç,can you please explain how

Comment: @Hari In a buck converter the inductor and the output cap form an LC filter. And the resonance frequency of this tank is important because you don't want the switching frequency to be very close to this resonance frequency as the output will possibly go unstable *(remember the resonant peak of the LC filter's curve)*. So you need to select the resonance frequency way below the switching frequency (e.g. somewhere around 1/8th of 1/10th of switching freq) to get 1) stable output and 2) adequate filtering (i.e. low ripple). But as the resonance frequency gets lower the reaction time gets longer.

Comment: ... That's because the L-C network appears in the transfer function and brings a crossover frequency. Higher crossover frequency means faster step response (or in other words, faster reaction to step changes of either input voltage or output loading). Larger L brings lower resonance (crossover) frequency therefore lower ripple, but longer reaction time as a consequence. That's why it's suggested to select the crossover (or resonance) frequency) as 1/8th to 1/10th of the switching frequency.

Comment: @RohatKılıç you should move those comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regulation depends on the gain of the controller.  If it has very high gain, as is usually the case, inverter parameters (PWM, inductor, capacitor) don't matter to DC response.

If gain is low, or PWM is fixed (open loop control), then it will depend, particularly as the gain equation changes from CCM to DCM if the inductance is in/de-creased far enough to cause such change.